# Writing Syntax Case When

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help from you guys regarding my task.

1.

```
SELECT * FROM DBMGR.RTREDC00
WHERE EDC_PARM = '9940-RESOE'
AND EDC_LOT = 'H28BRAD'`
```

[image]

2.

```
SELECT LSPEC.GET_LSPEC_MIN((SELECT RL_PO FROM DBMGR.RTRLOT01 WHERE 
    RL_FACILITY = 'MKLPROD' AND RL_LOT = 'H28BRAD'),'9940-RES','M') MIN_RAS,
    LSPEC.GET_LSPEC_MAX((SELECT RL_PO FROM DBMGR.RTRLOT01 WHERE RL_FACILITY 
    = 'MKLPROD' AND RL_LOT = 'H28BRAD'),'9940-RES','M') MAX_RAS
    FROM DUAL
```

[image]

I need to create syntax using `CASE WHEN` where `edc_value` between `MIN_RAS` and `MAX_RAS` the output will come out blank and if the `edc_value` not in between `MIN_RAS` and `MAX_RAS` the output will be `edc_lot`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
 --solution using common table expression and cross join
 WITH
      B AS ( --B for BOUNDS
           SELECT
                LSpec.Get_lspec_min(
                     (
                     SELECT rl_po 
                     FROM DBMgr.rtrlot01 
                     WHERE rl_facility = 'MKLPROD' 
                          AND rl_lot = 'H28BRAD'
                     ),
                     '9940-RES',
                     'M'
                ) AS min_ras, 
                LSpec.Get_lspec_max(
                     (
                     SELECT rl_po 
                     FROM DBMgr.rtrlot01 
                     WHERE rl_facility = 'MKLPROD' 
                          AND rl_lot = 'H28BRAD'
                     ),
                     '9940-RES',
                     'M'
                ) AS max_ras 
           FROM   dual
      )

 SELECT
      R.edc_facility,
      R.edc_parm,
      R.edc_lot,
      R.edc_unit,
      R.edc_waf_id,
      R.edc_seq,
      R.edc_value,
      CASE
           WHEN R.edc_value >= B.min_ras AND edc_value <= B.max_ras THEN NULL
           ELSE R.edc_lot
      END AS logic_requirement -- here is your requirement
 FROM DBMgr.RTREDC00 R
 CROSS JOIN B
 WHERE R.edc_parm = '9940-RESOE'
      AND R.edc_lot = 'H28BRAD'
 ;


 --solution using scalar subqueries within CASE statement of SELECT clause
 SELECT
      R.edc_facility,
      R.edc_parm,
      R.edc_lot,
      R.edc_unit,
      R.edc_waf_id,
      R.edc_seq,
      R.edc_value,
      CASE
           WHEN      edc_value >= (
                                    SELECT
                                         LSpec.Get_lspec_min(
                                              (
                                              SELECT rl_po 
                                              FROM DBMgr.rtrlot01 
                                              WHERE rl_facility = 'MKLPROD' 
                                                   AND rl_lot = 'H28BRAD'
                                              ),
                                              '9940-RES',
                                              'M'
                                         )
                                    FROM Dual
                                    )
                AND  edc_value <= (
                                    SELECT
                                         LSpec.Get_lspec_max(
                                              (
                                              SELECT rl_po 
                                              FROM DBMgr.rtrlot01 
                                              WHERE rl_facility = 'MKLPROD' 
                                                   AND rl_lot = 'H28BRAD'
                                              ),
                                              '9940-RES',
                                              'M'
                                         ) AS max_ras 
                                    FROM Dual
                                    )
                THEN NULL
           ELSE edc_lot
      END AS logic_requirement            
 FROM DBMgr.RTREDC00
 WHERE edc_parm = '9940-RESOE'
      AND edc_lot = 'H28BRAD'
 ;
```

Comment: When your requirement logic starts to get this complex (requires nesting an SQL statement within the arguments of a stored procedure), I think it's probably better to start thinking about using PL/SQL for readability.

I especially think this is true considering the repetition of WHERE parameters (e.g. 'H28BRAD') throughout.